# add pubmed id PMID to natbib references

Tags: citing, natbib

A journal where I want to submit requires a PMID after each reference, e.g.

> Westberg EE, Miller RA. The basis for using the Internet to support
>   the information needs of primary care. J Am Med Inform Assoc 1999
>   Jan-Feb;6(1):6-25. PMID:9925225

how can I do this in `natbib` ?

An example entry in my .bib file looks like this:

```
@article{koenig2015sharing,
    title={Sharing clinical trial data on patient level: Opportunities and challenges},
    author={Koenig, Franz and Slattery, Jim and Groves, Trish and Lang, Thomas and Benjamini, Yoav and Day, Simon and Bauer, Peter and Posch, Martin},
    journal={Biometrical Journal},
    volume={57},
    number={1},
    pages={8--26},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

Ideally, I could add a line like:
pmid = {12345678}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add a note tot the bibliography entry. A disadvantage is that you need to type the string `PMID:` within each note. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{sampleref.bib}
@article{koenig2015sharing,
    title={Sharing clinical trial data on patient level: Opportunities and challenges},
    author={Koenig, Franz and Slattery, Jim and Groves, Trish and Lang, Thomas and Benjamini, Yoav and Day, Simon and Bauer, Peter and Posch, Martin},
    journal={Biometrical Journal},
    volume={57},
    number={1},
    pages={8--26},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Wiley Online Library},
    note={PMID:9925225}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

See \citet{koenig2015sharing}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{sampleref.bib}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]